# How to show-hide elements based on current time

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i HAVE FOLLOWING 8 RADIO BUTTONS.

```
<h4>Date/time of delivery</h4>

<input type="radio" ng-model="order.delivery" value="1"> Today (09:00-12:00) <br/>
<input type="radio" ng-model="order.delivery" value="2"> Today (12:00-15:00) <br/>
<input type="radio" ng-model="order.delivery" value="3"> Today (15:00-18:00) <br/>
<input type="radio" ng-model="order.delivery" value="4"> Today (18:00-21:00) <br/>
<input type="radio" ng-model="order.delivery" value="5"> Tomorrow (09:00-12:00) <br/>
<input type="radio" ng-model="order.delivery" value="6"> Tomorrow (12:00-15:00) <br/>
<input type="radio" ng-model="order.delivery" value="7"> Tomorrow (15:00-18:00) <br/>
<input type="radio" ng-model="order.delivery" value="8"> Tomorrow (18:00-21:00)
```

I just want to show only 4 based on current time. For example if customer is placing the order today at 4PM, i want to show radio 4,5,6 and 7 to him.

How can i do that in angularJS.

Answer (score 0):

1. get timestamp(ms) from server (or trust client computer date)
2. get current hour and assign it to $scope variable

   ```
   $scope.currentHour = new Date(timestamp).getHours() //or .getUTCHours()
   ```
3. wrap 4 input each by

   ```
   <span ng-if="currentHour < 16">
       <input ....
   </span>
   <span ng-if="currentHour >= 16">
       <input ....
   </span>
   ```